# Setting text of text area in javascript

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Why won't this work to set text of text area?

```
document.getElementById("code").value = "hey farmer";
```

I even tried: `document.getElementById('code').value = "hey farmer";`

Is there a way to use getElementByName to set value?

Any help is appreciated

[html]

```
    <form>
        <textarea id="code" name="code">
            Lollllllll
</textarea>
    </form>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Are you sure it is a textarea and the id is `code` only and where have you placed this script?

Comment: Yes, the script is inside <script> tags

Comment: your code is working fine... what actually you are looking for?

Comment: The code looks correct

Comment: Either you have more than one element with the same ID, or you're running your script before the `code` element exists

Comment: I can read it just fine but can't write to it

Comment: @fdsfdfsdfdsw It would be nice, if you could save an example of this "read-only" behaviour to http://jsfiddle.net . Your problem is not reproduceable with the code you've provided. Btw, are you using a JS library, like CodeMirror?

Comment: @Teemu yes I'm using CodeMirror

Comment: @fdsfdfsdfdsw That's it then, those elements you see on the page are not the original elements. CodeMirror hides your original `textarea` and shows other elements instead. To solve this we need to see, how you've created the CM object(s). I've added the CodeMirror tag to your question, it's a very important part of your problem.

Comment: Okay well when I inspect the elements it shows as .CodeMirror-scroll

Comment: yes you can use document.getElementsByName('code') that will return array of elements. If you have single element then you can catch that element at 0th index

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine.  In

```
<textarea id=code>Foo</textarea>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('code').value = 'Bar'">
```

the text changes to "Bar" when the button is clicked.

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-textarea-value) says

> The value attribute must, on getting, return the element's API value; **on setting, it must set the element's raw value to the new value**, set the element's dirty value flag to true, and should then move the text entry cursor position to the end of the text field, unselecting any selected text and resetting the selection direction to none.

so this is speced behavior.

---

The problem is probably that you have multiple (or zero) elements with `id="code"` when your code runs so it's getting the wrong one.

---

Another problem may be that your `<textarea>` is immutable.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html says

> A textarea element is mutable if it is neither disabled nor has a readonly attribute specified.

Answer (score 0):

Native API

```
document.getElementById("id").value="Radha Mohan"
```

jQuery API

```
$("#couponRestrictionBean\\.includeProductIds").val("Radha")
```

Comment: And how is that better?

Comment: And why do you have `$("#couponRestrictionBean\.includeProductIds")`

Comment: $ is for jquery if you want to use only javascript use document.getElementById("id").value

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form>
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
        Lollllllll
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Replace To :

```
<form name="yourform">
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
        Lollllllll
   </textarea>
</form>


document.forms['yourform']['code'].value = 'yourvalue';
```

Comment: Why is this better than `getElementById()`?

Comment: he told that document.getElementById("code").value = "hey farmer"; is not working s.

Comment: It's not working because there's something causing it to not work. While this is an alternative for fetching elements, there's nothing to say that whatever is causing `getElementById` to fail won't also cause your code to fail. In other words, you're not addressing the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your script after your html, it would definitley work up. Below is the working code:

http://jsbin.com/EDOJEZ/2/edit?html,output

Again, I repeat, you gotta put your script block after your html markup.